# In Groovy is there a way to execute a `build` step only if there had been changes since the last build?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, conditional-statements, changeset

I need a way to run a job B from or before a job A, but I want to avoid unnecessary builds (i.e. without changes since the last run).

I'm currently using the `build` step to trigger job B from job A programmatically. And I know the `pollSCM` trigger which schedules a job to run every time and only if there had been changes for a given `scm` instance - taking `includedRegions` into account, i.e. it will only run if there had been changes for a given set of files/directories.

Is there a way to let `build` run conditionally the same way as `pollSCM` does, i.e. letting it run only if there are changes reported for the `scm` instance of the job I need to run?

Put differently job B (or it's artifacts) are a dependency for job A and I need it to be up to date (in terms of it's `scm` object), while at the same time avoiding redundant builds.

So the optimal solution would somehow look like

```
build(job: "JobB", if: changeSetNotEmpty())
```

A manual approach could compare the commitIds of `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("JobB").lastCompletedBuild` and the most recent on on that repo/branch but that wouldn't take `includedRegions` into account.

A better manual approach would check if `changeSet()` for a build that has not yet been triggered is empty. But is that even possible?

This problem seems to be quite common to me but even ChatGPT was only confused :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like below?

```
if(currentBuild.changeSets.size() > 0) {
   build(job: "JobB")
}
```

Comment: This checks for the `changeSets` of the current job (job "A") - I want to trigger job "B" only if there are changes for that job

Comment: @frans why don't you let Job "B" handle its own execution? Let it decide whether it needs to run or not. You can add a `when{}` condition in Job B to check the size of the changeSet. Job A will always execute Job B and if changes are not there Job B will not run. This seems simpler to me. Thoughts?

Comment: Well, if you need the artifacts of job B then those will be empty then. There must be a way to decide 'from outside' whether to take the last valid artifacts of job B or re-run it first. The only way to get rid of this would be to make sure job B always runs fast (e.g. with proper caching)